# Deleting an Entry in the join table of a Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: many-to-many, activejdbc

Using the example in the documentation: I have Doctors and Patients who are connected over a join table.
Now I delete a Patient from a Doctor, which works fine, i.e. the row in the join table vanishes:

```
doctor.remove(patient);
```

Is there a way that I can retrieve the remaining (n-1) patients without having to reload the Doctor from database, i.e.

```
doctor.getAll(Patient.class);
```

When doing this without reloading the Doctor I still get the just deleted entry.
Also cache purging does not work.
Only when I also reload the doctor from database the deleted entry is gone.
Is this the only way which works?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how the framework works. This code:

```
doctor.remove(patient);
```

removes the record from the join table. After that, calls:

```
doctor.getAll(Patient.class);
```

will not be returning removed patient. I tested this by writing additional test method in the https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/test/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/Many2ManyRelationshipTest.java.

Here is the test I added: https://gist.github.com/ipolevoy/821e986c5c7deb28a90d
As you can see, line 9 gets only one patient, because the other was removed on line 7.

You can turn logging on: http://javalite.io/logging to see what statements the framework is executing.

Comment: Logging looks ok. In your code i see that Doctor is cached and Patient is not. Is this intentional or does it matter ?

Comment: doctor is cached for a different test. In your case, this does not matter.

Comment: Really strange. Please have a look at my comments below your new gist.

Comment: @valley, I left a comment on the gist. If you can write a program that reproduces  your problem, feel free to open an issue: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues